# Total induction out of number

Tags: induction

If you have a variable x which is the outcome of a total induction of a real number, what is the formula to find out which induction it was.

For example:

x = 6: 3

x = 10: 4

x = 15: 5

x = 21: 6

Comment: What does "a total induction of a real number" mean?

Comment: Looks like $x = (n+1):2$, starting from $n=3$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology in the question is unfamiliar to me, but I *think* what it's asking is: suppose $x=1+\cdots+n$; then what is $n$ in terms of $x$?

Well, there's a nice simple formula: $x=\frac{n(n+1)}2$. Rearrange this a little to put it in the usual form for a quadratic equation in $n$: $n^2+n-2x=0$. And apply the usual quadratic formula: $n=\frac{\sqrt{8x+1}-1}2$. (The quadratic equation has *two* solutions but you evidently want the positive one.)

For instance, if $x=15$ this becomes $n=\frac{\sqrt{121}-1}2=\frac{11-1}2=5$.